# div with :href and a link over it all

Tags: css, html

Here is the code - div and imgage in it - on hover apears another div with text.
So the question is - how to make a link over this div (imgWrap) or (imgDescription) with text?
I want the whole div to be a link, but all my efforts ended with nothing. 
Thanks

link http://jsfiddle.net/6Dupu/

```
<style>
                .wr{
                    border:1px solid #ccc;
                    margin:10px;
                    float:left;
                }
                .imgWrap {
                  position: relative;
                  height: 175px;
                  width: 250px;


                }
                .imgWrap img{
                    height: 175px;
                    width: 250px;

                }
                .imgDescription {
                  position: absolute;
                  padding:20px;
                  overflow:hidden;
                  top: 0;
                  bottom: 0;
                  left: 0;
                  right: 0;
                  height:100%;
                  line-height:14px;
                  background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.8);
                  color: #fff;
                  visibility: hidden;
                  opacity: 0;
                   -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
                   -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
                   -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
                   transition: opacity 500ms;
                }


                .imgWrap:hover .imgDescription {
                  visibility: visible;
                  opacity: 1;
                }
            </style>
<div class="wr">
 <div class="imgWrap">
   <img src="somepic">
   <p class="imgDescription">
        <a href="" style="color:white;"><b>item_name</b></a> 
        <small style="display:block;padding:10px 0px;">item_text</small>
        <small>item_date</small>
  </p>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post relevant code with a fiddle, description of the issue and a snapshot of what it is happening and how you want it to work.

Comment: Show us the failed efforts, not (or at least, not just) the working code that you are trying to change.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. Should the overlay div be a link? Or should the image be a link where you can click through or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of showing a div with text when you hover the first div, use an anchor  and use it as block. (display: block)

Comment: If you do this, make sure to get rid of the ``<a href="" style="color:white;"><b>item_name</b></a>`` inside your ``imgDescription`` (which will then be ``<a>``). Because you're not allowed to nest anchors inside other anchors. It will mess up your layout otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Dupu/4/)

You have to add link on `div` click

Answer (score 1):

```
    <a href=""><div class="wr">
<div class="imgWrap">
    <img src="somepic"/>

  <p class="imgDescription">
         style="color:white;"><b>item_name</b>
            <small style="display:block;padding:10px 0px;">item_text</small>
            <small>item_date</small>

  </p>

</div>
</div>
</a>
```

And in your style set .imgDescription{marging:0px}- because in Firefox I see that "p" have some marge